# Mathematica is not able to integrate a function over an integral which Wolfram|Alpha can?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, evaluation

This is a semi-cross post from: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4519130/820472

Let $$f(x) = e^{\frac{-1}{1 - x^2}}, g(x) = \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}$$.

Then $$g(x)^2$$ has a finite area as is confirmed by the picture below:
[image]

Due to a specific example I am working with I need to use change of variables $u = \frac{\pi}{4}x$ so that $f$'s domain would be $$\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}\right), f(u) = e^{\frac{-1}{1 - \left(\frac{4x}{\pi}\right)^2}}$$.

As I am not that savy with Mathematica I reckoned that it would take me less time to compute everything with $f(u)$ than with $f(x)$ and somehow have Mathematica to perform the change of variables.

What I end up with is (where I am using the symbol $x$ instead of $u$)
[image]

which isn't at all what I wanted. Moreover, Mathematica seems to have some troubles even with the original integral as [image] while I expected to get the result of the first picture.

**Question:** Is there a fix to this problem, i.e. can I make Mathematica to compute the same integral which Wolfram|Alpha can.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. In order to replicate the difficulty you face in our own notebooks so that it can be studied and resolved promptly, we need you to provide copy-paste-able Mathematica code. Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting this as answer and not comment to show the code.

Please do not post images. This makes it hard to copy/paste. I had to type it from the image.

I see no problem in V 13.1. Analytically it can't integrate, but numerically it can. No errors are given as you show.

```
ClearAll[G, x];
G[x_] = D[D[Exp[-1/(1 - (4*x/Pi)^2)], x], x]
```

[image]

```
Quiet@Plot[G[x]^2, {x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}]
```

[image]

And

```
(4/Pi)*Integrate[G[x]^2, {x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}]
```

[image]

And

```
(4/Pi)*NIntegrate[G[x]^2, {x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}]
```

[image]

And for the Wolfram alpha image, it also works on V 13.1 with no problem and gives same answer

```
ClearAll[x]
expr = Exp[-2/(1 - x^2)]*(-2 + 4*x^2/(1 - x^2)^2 - 
      8*x^2/(1 - x^2))^2/(1 - x^2)^4
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
NIntegrate[expr, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which version are you using?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: My bad w.r.t. the missing codes, I apologize for the inconvenience. My version is *13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (January 29, 2022)* as that is the most recent version for Linux. That could be the issue. I will have to try with a Windows version later today to confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)];

g[x_] = D[f[x], {x, 2}] // Simplify

(* (E^(1/(-1 + x^2)) (-2 + 6 x^4))/(-1 + x^2)^4 *)

argmin = SolveValues[g[x] == 0, x, Reals];

Plot[g[x]^2, {x, -1, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {x, HoldForm[g[x]^2]},
  Axes -> False,
  Filling -> Axis,
  Epilog -> Inset[
    Plot[g[x]^2, {x, argmin[[1]], argmin[[2]]},
     Frame -> True,
     Axes -> False,
     Filling -> Axis]]] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
intN1 = NIntegrate[g[x]^2, {x, -1, 1}]

(* 10.8343 *)
```

[`IntegrateChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) is new in v13.1

```
int = IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][g[x]^2, {x, -1, 1}],
  u, u == Pi/4 x]
```

[image]

```
intN2 = (int /. Integrate -> NIntegrate) // Activate

(* 10.8343 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Analytically can be Integrate I use  **MellinTransform and InverseMellinTransform** a powerfull tools.

```
$Version
(*"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"*)

ClearAll[x, A]
expr = Exp[-A/(1 - x^2)]*(-2 + 4*x^2/(1 - x^2)^2 - 8*x^2/(1 - x^2))^2/(1 - x^2)^4
(*Where A = 2*)

M = MellinTransform[expr, A, s] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
(*(4 (1 - x^2)^s (1 - 3 x^4)^2 Gamma[s])/(-1 + x^2)^8*)

INT = Integrate[M, {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> Re[s] > 0]
(*ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2205 + 4 s (-439 + s (143 + (-20 + s) s))) Gamma[-7 + 
s] Gamma[s])/Gamma[-(5/2) + s], Re[s] > 7]*)

InverseMellinTransform[INT[[1]] // Expand, s, A]
(*(1/(A^3))(-1756 E^(-A/2) BesselK[4, A/2] + 
2205 Sqrt[\[Pi]] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2}}, {{-4, 3}, {}}, A] + 
572 Sqrt[\[Pi]] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4}, {}}, A] - 
80 Sqrt[\[Pi]] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4, 4}, {}}, A] + 
4 Sqrt[\[Pi]]
MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3, 3, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {}}, A])*)

ANSWER = % /. A -> 2 // Simplify
(*-((439 BesselK[4, 1])/(2 E)) + 
1/8 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2205 MeijerG[{{}, {1/2}}, {{-4, 3}, {}}, 2] + 
572 MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4}, {}}, 2] - 
80 MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4, 4}, {}}, 2] + 
4 MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 3, 3, 3}}, {{-4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {}}, 2])*)

ANSWER // N
(*10.8343*)
```

Answer with Latex form:
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{2}{1-x^2}\right) \left(-2+\frac{4 x^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}-\frac{8 x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^4} \,
   dx=-\frac{439 K_4(1)}{2 e}+\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{\pi } \left(2205 G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(2\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \\
 -4,3 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)+572 G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(2\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},3 \\
 -4,4,4 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-80 G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(2\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},3,3 \\
 -4,4,4,4 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)+4 G_{4,5}^{5,0}\left(2\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2},3,3,3 \\
 -4,4,4,4,4 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)\right)$$